# How to progress in calisthenics?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, bodyweight, calisthenics

In the past two years I have been doing basic calisthenics(Push-ups,Pull-ups, Chin-ups, Squats). I do 1500 push-ups one day and a total of 600 chin-ups and pull-ups the other day, and 250 squats everyday.. I have decided it is time to progress to more difficult body weight exercises such as planche, muscle up, flag pole etc..
I don't know where to fit the training for them into my workout routine. I workout M-Saturday and Sunday off. After I am done with my workout I am too exhausted to train for them, and I need advice on when to do them and significantly progress in them.

Comment: What are you goals? If you want to be able to do lots of pushups, pull ups, chins and bodyweight squats, I'd say you have achieved that.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've built up enough strength to be able to start moving onto some more advanced moves.

I'd say If you want to learn new movements, just start learning, training, building, improving as you did with your current exercises.

I'm guessing you didn't start out one day and do 1500 pushups without training!?

You just need to incorporate these new advanced movements into your current normal routine.
Also check YouTube for instructions/advice on proper form to prevent injury.

For example...

On your pull up day swap a few sets of pullups for muscle ups, 
*(before moving straight to muscle ups you may need to work on dips as you don't mention how many bodyweight dips you can do)* 
Also training to get more explosive at your pullups will help. so you can let go of the bar at the top and clap etc.

On your squats day throw in a few sets of alternating pistol squats, or bench lunges.

On push up day try handstand pushups or jumping/clapping pushups, wide grip, narrow grip, diamond grip... there's lots of pushup variations to make it more difficult.

I'd also suggest looking at core, and lower back training as doing more advanced static hold moves like flagpole planche etc. you're going to need to be able to recruit good balance and stabilization skills.

Get a couple of bricks or pushup bars and start trying to planche, see how much you can do and go from there... 5 seconds one day, 10 seconds the next and so on.

Also exercising in a weighted vest or with a heavy backpack will give you a jump in strength.

And if you're saying you're exhausted check that you're eating enough You don't want to burn out. especially if you're training 6 day splits!

But keep up the good work! 
Sounds like your progressing well!